# using shift operator with a number specified as #define

Tags: c, bit-shift

Could someone know the meaning of this  definition

```
#define RECV_BUFFER_LENGTH 4096

int main()
{


unsigned char buffer[RECV_BUFFER_LENGTH >> 1];
...
}
```

what is the length of buffer string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is somebody thinking they will profit something by not using more readable

```
unsigned char buffer[RECV_BUFFER_LENGTH / 2]
```

Actually this is evaluated at compile time. And if it was not, optimizer can translate that into faster less readable shift.

Answer (score 7):

You can translate it as follows:

```
unsigned char buffer[RECV_BUFFER_LENGTH >> 1];
unsigned char buffer[4096 >> 1]; // replace RECV_BUFFER_LENGTH by its definition
```

`>>` is the bit-wise right-shift operator. `4096 >> 1` means right-shift by one bit the number `4096` (in the binary representation). The binary representation of `4096` is modified as follows:

```
1000000000000 <-- this is 4096
 100000000000 <-- after shifting right by 1 bit, this is 2048
```

That gives:

```
unsigned char buffer[2048]; // buffer string is a 2048 element char array.
```